# How to spilt a string to get ABC( A B C) from AAA( A B C) (ABC:abc)

Tags: c#

I have a string like `"AAA( A B C) (ABC:abc)"`

I would like to split the string like `"AAA( A B C)"`
How we can achieve the using `String.Split()` method?

String could be AAA (ABC:abc) or AAA(A B C) BCD(X Y Z) (ABC:abc). My objective is to split it into 2 separate string from (ABC:abc).

Hope this will make it more clear.

Comment: You wouldn't use `string.Split` for that.

Comment: A bit of a background to why you want that exact part of the string would help to determine a good method to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `Split` and `Join` to do that, but it's not pretty or efficient:

```
string input = "AAA( A B C) (ABC:abc)";
string result = String.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').Take(4).ToArray())
```

An alternative would be to use `LastIndexOf` to locate the last space:

```
string result = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, you could use:

```
string s = "AAA( A B C) (ABC:abc)";
string t = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(')') + 1);
```

Comment: Why a downvote? Which is the reason? Is there something wrong with my code? Please, explain so I can correct my fault or delete this post!!

Answer (score 0):

[Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) is a better option in this case.

```
var pattern = @"(?<=\)) (?=\()";
var input = "AAA( A B C) (ABC:abc)";

var parts = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

Assert.AreEqual("AAA( A B C)", parts[0]);
```

If your string changes length at all, for example:

> AAAAAAA( A B C D) (ABCD:abcd)

This Regex would still match parts `AAAAAAA( A B C D)` and `(ABCD:abcd)`

Answer (score -1):

```
"AAA( A B C) (ABC:abc)".Split(new[] { ") (" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```